# Spring webclient POST method - Error handling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient

I have a Spring webflux service which expose a POST service.

```
RouterFunctions
.route(POST("/api/v1/service/order").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::submitOrder)
```

**Handler code**

Here calling a remote service as follows.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> submitOrder(final ServerRequest request) {
  try {
        return orderService.submitOrder(orderDto, order.getOrderId(),
                setting.getClientId()).flatMap(orderNum -> {
                    return noContent().build();
                 });
    } catch (WebClientException e) {
            return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

**Service code**

```
public Mono<ClientResponse> submitOrder(final OrderDto orderDto, 

        return webClient.post().uri(BASE_URL + "/api/v1/orders").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .bodyValue(report).retrieve().bodyToMono(ClientResponse.class);
    }
```

The remote service returns 201 for success and 4xx for error with the error message.

**Error Message**

```
<error>
    <message context="GLOBAL">Invalid order value</message>
</error>
```

I am not sure, how to read the remote service error message and send that to the client. The above code catches the exception and returns 500.

Comment: I have some questions. First: if an error occurs, what you want to do with the response body? Log it? Save it? Return it to someone? Second: does the error response returns 4xx http code in the case you've mentioned above?

Comment: I want to send the error message back to the caller with some exception.

Comment: first, you need to parse the XML, then check for the error object https://jsonformatter.org/xml-parser try this tool, then throw a ResponseStatusException with httpcode and the message